# scikit-learn cross_validation over-fitting or under-fitting

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm using scikit-learn cross_validation(http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) and get for example 0.82 mean score(r2_scorer).
How could I know do I have over-fitting or under-fitting using scikit-learn functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately I confirm that there is no built-in tool to compare train and test scores in a CV setup. The `cross_val_score` tool only reports test scores.

You can setup your own loop with the `train_test_split` function as in Ando's answer but you can also use any other CV scheme.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import SCORERS

scorer = SCORERS['r2']
cv = KFold(5)
train_scores, test_scores = [], []
for train, test in cv:
    regressor.fit(X[train], y[train])
    train_scores.append(scorer(regressor, X[train], y[train]))
    test_scores.append(scorer(regressor, X[test], y[test]))

mean_train_score = np.mean(train_scores)
mean_test_score = np.mean(test_scores)
```

If you compute the mean train and test scores with cross validation you can then find out if you are:

- Underfitting: the train score is far from the perfect score (which is 1.0 for r2)
- Overfitting: the train and test scores are not close from on another (the mean test score is significantly lower than the mean train score).

Note: you can be both significantly underfitting and overfitting at the same time if your model is inadequate and your data is too noisy.

Answer (score 0):

You should compare your scores when testing on training and testing data. If the scores are close to equal, you are likely underfitting. If they are far apart, you are likely overfitting (unless using a method such as random forest).

To compute the scores for both train and test data, you can use something along the following (assuming your data is in variables X and Y):

```
from sklearn import cross_validation

#do five iterations
for i in range(5):

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.4)
    #Your predictor, linear SVM in this example
    clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1).fit(X_train, y_train)

    print "Test score", clf.score(X_test, y_test)   
    print "Train score", clf.score(X_train, y_train)
```