# Checking if a model is over-fitting/under-fitting

Tags: python

I know that to check if a model is over-fitting or under-fitting, we need to get the score for the training and testing dataset and compare them. The thing is how to translate this into coding? Because I am doing this for the first time, I've done some searching and I've come across an old answer in here: ([scikit-learn cross_validation over-fitting or under-fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357705/scikit-learn-cross-validation-over-fitting-or-under-fitting)).

**Note: In the original answer `from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold` I have replaced this line with: `from sklearn.model_selection import KFold`**

Yet, when I run this, I get the error below. How to fix this?

```
X_normalized, y_for_normalized = scaled_df[[ "Part's Z-Height (mm)","Part's Solid Volume (cm^3)","Layer Height (mm)","Printing/Scanning Speed (mm/s)","Part's Orientation (Support's volume) (cm^3)"]], scaled_df [["Climate change (kg CO2 eq.)","Climate change, incl biogenic carbon (kg CO2 eq.)","Fine Particulate Matter Formation (kg PM2.5 eq.)","Fossil depletion (kg oil eq.)","Freshwater Consumption (m^3)","Freshwater ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Freshwater Eutrophication (kg P eq.)","Human toxicity, cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Human toxicity, non-cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Ionizing Radiation (Bq. C-60 eq. to air)","Land use (Annual crop eq. yr)","Marine ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Marine Eutrophication (kg N eq.)","Metal depletion (kg Cu eq.)","Photochemical Ozone Formation, Ecosystem (kg NOx eq.)","Photochemical Ozone Formation, Human Health (kg NOx eq.)","Stratospheric Ozone Depletion (kg CFC-11 eq.)","Terrestrial Acidification (kg SO2 eq.)","Terrestrial ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)"]]


new_model = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=9,
                                  min_samples_split=10,random_state=0)




   import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import SCORERS
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

scorer = SCORERS['r2']
cv = KFold(5)
train_scores, test_scores = [], []
for train, test in cv.split(X_normalized):
    new_model.fit(X[train], y[train])
    train_scores.append(scorer(new_model, X[train], y[train]))
    test_scores.append(scorer(new_model, X[test], y[test]))

mean_train_score = np.mean(train_scores)
mean_test_score = np.mean(test_scores)





---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/mm/r4gnnwl948zclfyx12w803040000gn/T/ipykernel_73165/4218536717.py in <module>
      7 train_scores, test_scores = [], []
      8 for train, test in cv.split(X_normalized):
----> 9     new_model.fit(X[train], y[train])
     10     train_scores.append(scorer(new_model, X[train], y[train]))
     11     test_scores.append(scorer(new_model, X[test], y[test]))

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3462             if is_iterator(key):
   3463                 key = list(key)
-> 3464             indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1)[1]
   3465 
   3466         # take() does not accept boolean indexers

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis)
   1312             keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = ax._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
   1313 
-> 1314         self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis)
   1315 
   1316         if needs_i8_conversion(ax.dtype) or isinstance(

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis)
   1372                 if use_interval_msg:
   1373                     key = list(key)
-> 1374                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   1375 
   1376             not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())

KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36,\n            37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53,\n            54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70,\n            71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87,\n            88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99],\n           dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [user manual](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#k-fold), you need to call `cv.split(X)` to get an iterator:

```py
for train, test in cv.split(X):
    regressor.fit(X[train], y[train])
    ...
```

---

Also keep in mind that `train` and `test` are lists of indices. For `numpy`, this is not a problem (in the sense that indexing by a list of indices instead of a single one will produce what you expect it to produce), but it's not true for regular `list`s, or in general objects that are indexable.

Comment: Thank you. I am getting another error. I've updated my code.

Comment: @Z47 I've updated my answer. However, it would be better if you opened a new thread if you have a new question, because the idea of forums is to keep track of the question you asked (which is now not visible anymore) alongside the answer.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind thank you. I am a bit confused about this. Still can't fix it. Can you comment on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
X_normalized, y_for_normalized = scaled_df[[ "Part's Z-Height (mm)","Part's Solid Volume (cm^3)","Layer Height (mm)","Printing/Scanning Speed (mm/s)","Part's Orientation (Support's volume) (cm^3)"]], scaled_df [["Climate change (kg CO2 eq.)","Climate change, incl biogenic carbon (kg CO2 eq.)","Fine Particulate Matter Formation (kg PM2.5 eq.)","Fossil depletion (kg oil eq.)","Freshwater Consumption (m^3)","Freshwater ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Freshwater Eutrophication (kg P eq.)","Human toxicity, cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Human toxicity, non-cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Ionizing Radiation (Bq. C-60 eq. to air)","Land use (Annual crop eq. yr)","Marine ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Marine Eutrophication (kg N eq.)","Metal depletion (kg Cu eq.)","Photochemical Ozone Formation, Ecosystem (kg NOx eq.)","Photochemical Ozone Formation, Human Health (kg NOx eq.)","Stratospheric Ozone Depletion (kg CFC-11 eq.)","Terrestrial Acidification (kg SO2 eq.)","Terrestrial ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)"]]


new_model = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=9,
                                  min_samples_split=10,random_state=0)

import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import SCORERS
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

scorer = SCORERS['r2']

cv = KFold(5)
train_scores, test_scores = [], []

for train, test in cv.split(X_normalized):
    new_model.fit(X_normalized[train], y_for_normalized[train])
    train_scores.append(scorer(new_model, X_normalized[train], y_for_normalized[train]))
    test_scores.append(scorer(new_model, X_normalized[test], y_for_normalized[test]))

mean_train_score = np.mean(train_scores)
mean_test_score = np.mean(test_scores)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).