# Error doing CV for training and testing datasets

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to do CV for my training and testing datasets. I am using LinearRegressor. However, when I run the code, I get the error below. How to fix this? Is my code for the CV section correct? Thank you for your help.......................................................

Reference for the CV code: [scikit-learn cross_validation over-fitting or under-fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357705/scikit-learn-cross-validation-over-fitting-or-under-fitting)

```
    X_normalized, y_for_normalized = scaled_df[[ "Part's Z-Height (mm)","Part's Solid Volume (cm^3)","Layer Height (mm)","Printing/Scanning Speed (mm/s)","Part's Orientation (Support's volume) (cm^3)"]], scaled_df [["Climate change (kg CO2 eq.)","Climate change, incl biogenic carbon (kg CO2 eq.)","Fine Particulate Matter Formation (kg PM2.5 eq.)","Fossil depletion (kg oil eq.)","Freshwater Consumption (m^3)","Freshwater ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Freshwater Eutrophication (kg P eq.)","Human toxicity, cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Human toxicity, non-cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Ionizing Radiation (Bq. C-60 eq. to air)","Land use (Annual crop eq. yr)","Marine ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Marine Eutrophication (kg N eq.)","Metal depletion (kg Cu eq.)","Photochemical Ozone Formation, Ecosystem (kg NOx eq.)","Photochemical Ozone Formation, Human Health (kg NOx eq.)","Stratospheric Ozone Depletion (kg CFC-11 eq.)","Terrestrial Acidification (kg SO2 eq.)","Terrestrial ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)"]].
```

```
Part's Z-Height (mm)    Part's Solid Volume (cm^3)  Layer Height (mm)   Printing/Scanning Speed (mm/s)  Part's Orientation (Support's volume) (cm^3)    Climate change (kg CO2 eq.) Climate change, incl biogenic carbon (kg CO2 eq.)   Fine Particulate Matter Formation (kg PM2.5 eq.)    Fossil depletion (kg oil eq.)   Freshwater Consumption (m^3)    Freshwater ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)  Freshwater Eutrophication (kg P eq.)    Human toxicity, cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)  Human toxicity, non-cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)  Ionizing Radiation (Bq. C-60 eq. to air)    Land use (Annual crop eq. yr)   Marine ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)  Marine Eutrophication (kg N eq.)    Metal depletion (kg Cu eq.) Photochemical Ozone Formation, Ecosystem (kg NOx eq.)   Photochemical Ozone Formation, Human Health (kg NOx eq.)    Stratospheric Ozone Depletion (kg CFC-11 eq.)   Terrestrial Acidification (kg SO2 eq.)  Terrestrial ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)
0   0.258287    0.005030    0.0 0.666667    0.040088    0.069825    0.056976    0.083205    0.010373    0.113808    0.104798    0.086400    0.110358    0.012836    0.091120    0.108676    0.090401    0.087426    0.125608    0.079028    0.080495    0.078380    0.082404    0.045040
1   0.258287    0.005030    0.2 0.666667    0.036597    0.041682    0.022880    0.074884    0.004841    0.045640    0.102285    0.082884    0.044202    0.005414    0.086700    0.105749    0.087161    0.084130    0.060373    0.072878    0.073529    0.074829    0.075438    0.018122
2   0.258287    0.009557    0.4 0.666667    0.031013    0.033310    0.012113    0.073035    0.003458    0.023401    0.102914    0.082494    0.022690    0.003231    0.086279    0.105749    0.086937    0.084130    0.039708    0.071341    0.071981    0.074698    0.073447    0.009856
3   0.258287    0.009054    0.6 0.666667    0.031013    0.029213    0.006954    0.072111    0.002766    0.012936    0.102914    0.082103    0.012524    0.001921    0.086069    0.105423    0.086602    0.084130    0.029579    0.070572    0.071207    0.074435    0.072452    0.005723
4   0.258287    0.010060    1.0 0.666667    0.031711    0.025650    0.001795    0.071803    0.003458    0.002180    0.103542    0.082884    0.002063    0.001048    0.086490    0.106074    0.087049    0.084542    0.019449    0.070572    0.071207    0.074961    0.072452    0.001908
5   0.258287    0.005030    0.0 0.000000    0.040088    0.074279    0.062360    0.084129    0.011065    0.125000    0.104798    0.086790    0.121114    0.014146    0.091330    0.108676    0.091519    0.087426    0.136143    0.080566    0.081269    0.078511    0.083400    0.049385
6   0.258287    0.038226    0.0 0.666667    0.040088    0.097791    0.074249    0.109091    0.038036    0.135174    0.129299    0.111788    0.132164    0.024625    0.116582    0.133725    0.116102    0.112970    0.154781    0.105166    0.106037    0.104419    0.108280    0.064222
7   0.137212    0.004527    0.0 0.666667    0.030314    0.058247    0.046433    0.076117    0.003458    0.095349    0.099144    0.080150    0.092382    0.008907    0.084806    0.102821    0.084702    0.081246    0.106159    0.072878    0.073529    0.072199    0.075438    0.035608
8   0.137212    0.004527    0.2 0.666667    0.029616    0.035269    0.017721    0.069954    0.000000    0.037355    0.098516    0.078197    0.036246    0.002794    0.082281    0.101520    0.082803    0.080010    0.051053    0.068266    0.068885    0.070489    0.070462    0.013247
9   0.137212    0.010060    0.4 0.666667    0.028918    0.031706    0.010543    0.072111    0.002766    0.020494    0.102285    0.081712    0.019891    0.002358    0.085438    0.104773    0.086043    0.083306    0.036467    0.070572    0.071207    0.073908    0.072452    0.008372
10  0.137212    0.010060    0.6 0.666667    0.028220    0.027431    0.005384    0.070878    0.001383    0.010320    0.101657    0.080931    0.010019    0.001484    0.084806    0.104448    0.085373    0.082894    0.026742    0.069803    0.070433    0.073251    0.071457    0.004345
11  0.137212    0.009557    1.0 0.666667    0.027522    0.022800    0.000000    0.069029    0.000000    0.000000    0.101029    0.080150    0.000000    0.000000    0.083754    0.103472    0.084367    0.081658    0.016613    0.068266    0.068885    0.072330    0.070462    0.000000
12  0.137212    0.004527    0.0 0.000000    0.030314    0.062879    0.052266    0.077042    0.004149    0.107122    0.099144    0.080541    0.103875    0.010217    0.085227    0.102821    0.085037    0.081658    0.117099    0.073647    0.074303    0.072462    0.076433    0.040165
13  0.137212    0.037723    0.0 0.666667    0.030314    0.085857    0.063257    0.102003    0.031120    0.116134    0.123645    0.105929    0.112568    0.020695    0.110269    0.127544    0.110515    0.106790    0.134522    0.098247    0.099071    0.097843    0.101314    0.053624
14  0.077118    0.004527    0.0 0.666667    0.054050    0.080335    0.064827    0.091217    0.018672    0.126453    0.111709    0.093821    0.122145    0.016766    0.098485    0.115833    0.098223    0.094842    0.139789    0.087485    0.088235    0.085876    0.090366    0.052777
15  0.077118    0.004527    0.0 0.000000    0.054050    0.085144    0.070884    0.092450    0.019364    0.138081    0.111709    0.094211    0.133638    0.018075    0.099116    0.116158    0.098223    0.094842    0.151135    0.088253    0.089009    0.086139    0.091361    0.057864
16  0.077118    0.004527    0.0 0.333333    0.054050    0.082472    0.067519    0.091834    0.019364    0.132267    0.111709    0.094211    0.127744    0.017639    0.098695    0.116158    0.098223    0.094842    0.144652    0.087485    0.088235    0.086007    0.091361    0.054684
```

```
     lin_regressor = LinearRegression()
    
    # pass the order of your polynomial here  
    poly = PolynomialFeatures(1)
    
    # convert to be used further to linear regression
    X_transform = poly.fit_transform(x_train)
    
    # fit this to Linear Regressor
    linear_regg=lin_regressor.fit(X_transform,y_train).
```

```
     import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import SCORERS
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

scorer = SCORERS['r2']

cv = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=0,shuffle=True)
train_scores, test_scores = [], []

for train, test in cv.split(X_normalized):
    X_transform2 = poly.fit_transform(X_normalized)
    OL=lin_regressor.fit(X_transform2.iloc[train], y_for_normalized.iloc[train])
    tr_21 = OL.score(X_train, y_train)
    ts_21 = OL.score(X_test, y_test)
    print ("Train score:", tr_21) # from documentation .score returns r^2
    print ("Test score:", ts_21)   # from documentation .score returns r^2
    
    train_scores.append(tr_21)
    test_scores.append(ts_21)



print ("The Mean for Train scores is:",(np.mean(train_scores)))
    
print ("The Mean for Test scores is:",(np.mean(test_scores)))
```

'''

```
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/mm/r4gnnwl948zclfyx12w803040000gn/T/ipykernel_73165/2276765730.py in <module>
     10 for train, test in cv.split(X_normalized):
     11     X_transform2 = poly.fit_transform(X_normalized)
---> 12     OL=lin_regressor.fit(X_transform2.iloc[train], y_for_normalized.iloc[train])
     13     tr_21 = OL.score(X_train, y_train)
     14     ts_21 = OL.score(X_test, y_test)

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
model=LinearRegression()
kfold_validation=KFold(10)

import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

results=cross_val_score(model,X,y,cv=kfold_validation)
print(results)
print(np.mean(results))
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't want this, I want the score for the training and testing to check for overfitting.

Comment: @Z47 insted of x and y use x_test,y_test and x_train and y_train.

Comment: Thank you but what's wrong with my code?

Comment: So,your  error is that iloc can only be used with pandas dataframe but you are using it on numpy array. change the numpy array to dataframe using                                           
   "data = pd.DataFrame(numpy_array)".

Comment: Thanks would you mind using my code and posting an answer of the CV portion of the code?

Comment: yes just give me 5 minutes. but can you show me how your y_normalised looks. Cause i can help you with some code that you can easily understand or can you just show me the dataset it would be more easy. dataset the raw one i will give the code for standardization as well.

Comment: `y_normalized` is the last 19 columns in my matrix.

Comment: ok so a tip the class feature or "Y" we don't normalize or standardize the output  feature . 5 min sending code.

Comment: Yes, I've read about that. But I've also found other references recommending normalizing the y (response) as well.

Comment: acutally no if you do so it wont help sinde in the end you have to inverse transform the y feature and good datascientist wont recommend scaling your ouput class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the edited code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import SCORERS
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

scorer = SCORERS['r2']

cv = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=0,shuffle=True)
train_scores, test_scores = [], []

for train, test in cv.split(X_normalized):
    X_transform2 = poly.fit_transform(X_normalized)
    OL=lin_regressor.fit(X_transform2, y_for_normalized)
    tr_21 = OL.score(X_train, y_train)
    ts_21 = OL.score(X_test, y_test)
    print ("Train score:", tr_21) # from documentation .score returns r^2
    print ("Test score:", ts_21)   # from documentation .score returns r^2
    
    train_scores.append(tr_21)
    test_scores.append(ts_21)



print ("The Mean for Train scores is:",(np.mean(train_scores)))
    
print ("The Mean for Test scores is:",(np.mean(test_scores)))
```

Note - I have some concernd how does your  y_for_normalise looks.
cause i think you code is itself correct you are now visualising the data correctly.
check this code.

Comment: ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 6 is different from 5)

Comment: then i have lack of info(i can visualize how the data is) if possible pls try my method its a simple easy to understand code.