# Warning using SVR GridSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search, gridsearchcv

I am trying to do hyper-parameter tuning for SVR. however, I am getting the warning below. How to fix this?

**NOTE: I have 19 outputs and looks like SVR supports only a single output?**

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

svr = SVR()

from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kfold_splitter = KFold(n_splits=6, random_state = 42,shuffle=True)

svr_random = RandomizedSearchCV(svr,
                  param_distributions = {'kernel' : ('linear', 'poly', 'rbf', 'sigmoid'),
                                         'C' : [1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6,6.5,7,7.5,8,8.5,9,9.5,10],
                                         'degree' : [3,8],
                                         'coef0' : [0.01,0.1,0.5],
                                         'gamma' : ('auto','scale'),
                                         'tol': [1e-3, 1e-4, 1e-5, 1e-6]},
                  n_iter=100,
                  cv=kfold_splitter, 
                  n_jobs=-1,
                  random_state=42,
                  scoring='r2')

svr_random.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(svr_random.best_params_)
```

**Error:**

```
Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: Why are you using `KFold` explicitly as `cv`?  [RandomizedSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) uses KFold and StratifiedKFold internally.

Comment: @GodWin THANKS. Does SVR support only a single output?

Comment: Single Output? In what sense?

Comment: @GodWin I have 19 outputs/responses in my model. I found this post talking about how SVR supports a single output only.https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153853/regression-with-scikit-learn-with-multiple-outputs-svr-or-gbm-possible#:~:text=SVR%20naturally%20only%20supports%20single%2Doutput%20regression.

Comment: Yes. You cannot predict multiple regressor output with this.

Comment: @GodWin thank you for the confirmation. I am stuck on my code since 2 days, since you're a very reputable member can I get your help to fix an issue in my code on this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73392074/whats-the-mistake-i-am-doing-in-this-cv-code?noredirect=1#comment129610127_73392074