# Trying to check for overfitting

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to use the code in the link below to check for overfitting, however, I am getting an error, any clues what I am doing wrong?

Code reference: [scikit-learn cross_validation over-fitting or under-fitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357705/scikit-learn-cross-validation-over-fitting-or-under-fitting)

```
lin_regressor = LinearRegression()

poly = PolynomialFeatures(2)

X_transform = poly.fit_transform(x_train)

linear_regg=lin_regressor.fit(X_transform,y_train) 

from sklearn.metrics import SCORERS
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

scorer = SCORERS['r2']

cv = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=0,shuffle=True)

train_scores, test_scores = [], []

for train, test in cv.split(X_normalized):
    X_transform2 = poly.fit_transform(X_normalized)
    OL = lin_regressor.fit(X_transform2[train], y_for_normalized.iloc[train])
    tr_21 = OL.scorer(X_transform2[train], y_for_normalized.iloc[train])
    ts_21 = OL.scorer(X_transform2[test], y_for_normalized.iloc[test])
    print("Train score:", tr_21)  
    print("Test score:", ts_21)  

    train_scores.append(tr_21)
    test_scores.append(ts_21)


print("The Mean for Train scores is:", (np.mean(train_scores)))

print("The Mean for Test scores is:", (np.mean(test_scores)))
```

Error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/mm/r4gnnwl948zclfyx12w803040000gn/T/ipykernel_13098/1734683602.py in <module>
     12     # [] for X_transform2, .iloc[] for y_for_normalized
     13     OL = lin_regressor.fit(X_transform2[train], y_for_normalized.iloc[train])
---> 14     tr_21 = OL.scorer(X_transform2[train], y_for_normalized.iloc[train])
     15     ts_21 = OL.scorer(X_transform2[test], y_for_normalized.iloc[test])
     16     print("Train score:", tr_21)  # from documentation .score returns r^2

AttributeError: 'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'scorer'
```

Comment: Your regressor `OL` doesn't have a `scorer` method, as the error says.  The linked code and yours defines a function called `scorer`, so just drop the `OL.` from those lines.  (Alternatively, `OL` has a `score` method which in this case should do the same thing.)

Comment: so I define a scorer for `OL`? When I use `OL.score` I get the R^2 which is the default scorer for `.score` I am trying to use RMSE instead of R^2 and this is where I am stuck. Would you post your corrected version for the code? Thanks. –